# How to render a brain image + heatmap using cubes instead of points?

Tags: mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I'm trying to plot a PET image with a heatmap for showing regions of interests using Mayavi. The render looks of but once I zoom I can see the points instead. What I want is to use cubes instead of points, so there are no spaces in between.

If you look at the border of this image you will see that they are points, not squares.

[image]

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
points = mlab.points3d(x_flat, y_flat, z_flat, opacity_values, transparent = True)
```

In which `opacity_values` is the brain PET image + heatmap.

How can I make a similar plot but with squares instead of points, so there are no empty spaces between points? Or at least that it doesn't look with empty spaces between points.